# Prometheus Query when a service is restarted

Tags: prometheus, grafana, pcf

I need to create a prom alert for when a service of pcf app is restarted. Can someone help me query it?
I tried the below query. But, It's showing o/p single time.

```
resets(max(process_uptime_seconds{}) by (app,.....)[5m:1m]) > 0
```

The alert should trigger for each restart

Comment: What "o/p" stands for? In general, please, avoid abbreviations unless they are 100% clear from context even for layman.

Comment: If you simply want to check if all processes of some `app` were restarted less then 5 minutes ago you can simply use `max(process_uptime_seconds{}) by (app,.....) < 5*60`. Does this query produce what you need? Or am I missing your idea?